# Intersection of sets span a vectorspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-Vectorspace, and let $B_1,B_2, ...$ be subsets of $V$ such that $B_1\supseteq B_2 \supseteq ...$ and for all $i\in\mathbb{N} \setminus \{ 0\} $ is $\langle B_i \rangle = V$. Prove or disprove that $\langle \cap_{i\in\mathbb{N}} B_i \rangle =V$.
The hint from our professor was that this is not true.
Let's choose $B_k$ such that it is a subset of all other $B_i$ and also the smallest set. So every vector of $B_k$ is also in every other $B_i$. Therefore, the intersection of all $B_i$ would be $B_k$ and we know that $\langle B_k \rangle = V$ which would make the statement true. Where am I wrong? Any solution or hint would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody said that we have only finitely many $B_i$'s. Suppose that $V=\Bbb K$ and that$$B_n=\left\{x\in\Bbb K\mid|x|<\frac1n\right\}.$$Then $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\langle B_n\rangle=\Bbb K$. However, $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}B_n=\{0\}$, and so$$\left\langle\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}B_n\right\rangle=\{0\}.$$